# Can a friend buy me a game using my Xbox One account on their Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

If a friend buys a game on their Xbox One while on my account, will I be able to play the game on my console as well?

Answer (score 5):

If they are using your account (Which I would never recommend due to security concerns) they could purchase a game doing that on their Xbox One and install it on their console. However the friend will not be able to play the game unless they own it or are using your account. But yes, it is possible to buy games on another console. Honestly it would just be easier to get a card and have you purchase the game instead.

Edit: Another alternative to do this (thanks to [Timmy Jim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/163757/timmy-jim) for finding this) is to link both your and your friend's consoles together which would allow you to share games together and also allows you both to play the game at the same time. Here is a link Timmy provided on how to do it.

Source: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/my-home-xbox

Comment: I will add that if you link you and your friends console together (make your console the home console), whenever you purchase something, your friend will also get it at no additional charge. Me and my friend (who lives across the nation) do this, and we save so much money. We usually rotate on who buys what. My friend will buy an Xbox code to add cash to an account and send me the code in a text.  I'll then add the money to my account, purchase the item, and we both get the item.

Comment: Huh, I did not know you could do that. However this question does seem to be asking more of just if his friend logs into his account if he can buy stuff for him.

Comment: Right, but this is a good alternative (at least I think). Here is [a guide](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/my-home-xbox) on how to do this.

Comment: I'll give you credit in my answer and post that link you provided, seems like a much safer alternative than just letting your friend run rampant through your account.

Comment: Also just to clarify, both you and your friend can play the same games at the same time.  When I tell people about this home console setting, that's often a question asked.

Comment: I was just about to ask about that since I know Steam Family sharing doesn't allow simultaneous playing of the game game.